# Data Validation Autocomplete

Tags: excel, vba, validation, autocomplete

I have a data validation box coded with VBA (please see below.) I have done loads of reading and cannot find a way to do autocomplete when someone types in the data validation cell.

Most people suggest a combobox, but I have not found a way to place a combo box inside a specific cell. I want it so that if someone tries to copy the row the combobox resides in, they can then paste another row with another combobox.

With data validation, this already is possible, but it does not have the autocomplete ability.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub DataValidation()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MachineList")

Set Range1 = WS.Range("A7") 'This is the cell the data validation is placed in.
Set Range2 = WS2.Range("A2:A64") 'This will change if the Machine List gains or loses machines.

    With Range1.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
            Formula1:="='" & WS2.Name & "'!" & Range2.Address
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = "Machine Name"
        .ErrorTitle = "ERROR: Invalid Machine"
        .InputMessage = "Please enter or select a machine..."
        .ErrorMessage = "You have entered an invalid machine. Please try again."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does [https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html) help?

Comment: The easiest trick to this is to have a bunch of hidden rows with the contents of the drop down list.  That way, because those values are in the above cells, if a user is typing Excel will try to autocomplete based on above row values.  Just make sure those content rows are hidden.

Comment: Hi tigeravatar, I have been unable to get that to work- It will do it if the list is short, but when I put in my entire list, it doesnt autocomplete... Also, the list may change at some point so I would like to avoid this route if possible. I appreciate your help!

Comment: HI Scott, that seems to be the code behind the combo box. While I would be open to using it, I need to find a way to place the combo box within a cell , so that the user can copy it and the row it is in. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @mitchmitch24 the only combobox you can have *inside a cell* is the data validation drop-down, which doesn't do autocomplete. If you want autocomplete, you need something else, and that something else won't be *in the cell*, because it's not data validation. You gotta pick your battles. You can make an ActiveX control *look* like it's "in the cell", and you can keep data validation in that cell and link it to your ActiveX dropdown, so you have the data in the cell that needs it *and* you have a dropdown with autocomplete for it.

Comment: When you say you can link the data validation to an activex dropdown, how would that work? That may be a good solution. (And yeah, I after my googling I kinda figured this would be a pick your battle situation, but wanted to double check I wasnt missing something simple.) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Right-click the ActiveX dropdown, select *properties*, and put `A1` into the `LinkedCell` property. Type something into the dropdown and watch cell `A1` populate accordingly. If `A1` has data validation, you will not be able to confirm an invalid value into the dropdown.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I have used that. So while that does populate that box, once the row is copied and re pasted, the drop down selection may be different for the new row, so that might not work. I appreciate your help though Mat!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. Keep in mind Excel is a spreadsheet, not a web app. If you want client-side validation and shiny UI in a data entry / CRUD app, write it in JavaScript and run it in a browser, not in Excel.

Comment: It is basically a form to select a certain type of machine (by its name) and then in the cell to the right of the selection, fill out a description of what happened (if it was broken, needs new parts, etc.) The users have to create more rows if more issues happen during their shift. I am trying to make it as user friendly as possible, but I agree with you- Excel can be quite limited for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no perfect solution, here is one I found that was easy to implement and edit:

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal14.html#works (Single cell click/selection)
http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal11.html#works (Double cell click)

Basically, when a user clicks on a data validation cell, this code places a combobox directly over it, (that fills using the same formula as the data validation.) This way the user can still have autocomplete, but doesnt have to worry about the combobox moving if the cells change in any way.